# Wildmenu "closes" when opening a single item directory

Tags: vim

TLDR;

I want to open `wildmenu` with `<Tab>` and keep it open until I open a file.

---

Suppose that I have the following directory structure:

```
./file1
./file2
./dir1/file3
./dir1/dir2/file4
./dir1/dir2/file5
./dir1/dir3/dir4/file6
```

I normally use `wildmenu` and the arrow keys to navigate through the directories. If I have `file1` open and want to open `file5` I can navigate through the directories like this:

```
:tabe dir1/ <Tab>
:tabe dir1/dir2 dir3 file3 <Down>
:tabe dir1/dir2/file4 file5 <Right>
:tabe dir1/dir2/file5 file4 <Enter>
```

But when I try to do the same to open `file6` the `wildmenu` will close on `dir4` because this is the only file inside `dir3`, I want to keep the `wildmenu` open even if there is only one choice for a given directory so that I can keep navigating with just the arrow keys (without doing `<Tab>` in every directory that has only one file inside)

Edit: [my .vimrc](https://github.com/hackaugusto/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try these settings in your .vimrc:

```
set wildmode=list:longest,full
set wildmenu
```

Instead of the DOS cmd. window style of searching for files by repeating hitting tab, this setting makes it work like tab completion in a `bash` shell.

#### Screenshot of vim

[image: ss of vim w/ wildmenus on]

#### References

- [How to effectively use VIM: wildmenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511253/how-to-effectively-use-vim-wildmenu)
- [Great wildmode/wildmenu and console mouse](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Great_wildmode/wildmenu_and_console_mouse)

Comment: `longest:full` did not work, I actually tried them all and I like the `wildmode=full` the most, the only problem is that wildmenu closes itself when there is only one file in the directory, because of that I can't keep navigating through the filesystem hierarchy

Comment: Sorry that was an old syntax, try the list:longest,full. I've updated the answer with that too.